# Getting song metadata from Wowza Streaming Engine

Tags: android, audio-streaming, wowza, shoutcast

I'm trying to get the song metadata such as title and artist, from a Wowza Streaming Server.

I found some tutorials, but for the Flash language, which is captured from the RTMP.

I have always worked with SHOUTcast, server and it just access the address http://yourdomain.com:15692/currentsong?sid=1 to get the name of the song.

**Has anyone worked with Wowza on Android, and succeeded in taking the name of the song?**

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using the RTMP side of Wowza?

Comment: I'm actually in a fight. I've tried RTSP and "http/M3U8". From the Android 5 "M3U8" works very well. But in earlier versions'm struggling with the RMSP and does not work right. It is the first time working with WOWZA. In other experiences I worked with SHOUTcast and worked perfectly via "http" from Android 2.3.3 to the 5. If you have any tips, I would be very grateful.

Comment: [RTSP](http://wz2.dnip.com.br/brasiliensefc/brasiliensefc.stream) and [http/m3u8](http://wz2.dnip.com.br/brasiliensefc/brasiliensefc.stream/plailist.m3u8). On RTSP change the http:// to rtsp://.

Comment: For compatibility, I've always had the best luck with HTTP.  HLS is catching on and that will be great to see, but support isn't entirely there yet.  In any case, if you were using HTTP with SHOUTcast-style metadata, I have a nice API you can use where you just pass the URL to get the metadata:  http://api.audiopump.co/metadata/getStreamMetadata?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.audiopump.co%2Fradioreddit%2Fmain_mp3_128k&apiKey=UB1z5zhLThZ4pBnhBUyPQjSGLSGpgvK6  You can get an API key at http://audiopump.co/accounts/  Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't help with the RTMP stuff at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your link return 502 Bad Gateway. As soon as I can play the audio in an acceptable manner in Android, I will work again on the issue of metadata. Apparently the WOWZA audio codec does not play correctly on Android.

Comment: Please try that API link again. I had a temporary issue that is now resolved.  Thanks.